# gitlab-ci.yml configuration to handle multiple conditional parent child pipeline

Tags: maven, gitlab, yaml, pom.xml, gitlab-ci

I have a repository setup where there are multiple maven projects, 2 are main projects and rest are dependency project. I would like to configure gitlab-ci.yml file to handle changes in dependency to project to trigger build for corresponding main project.

Here is the example of project structure. There are 2 main projects and rest are dependency project. Main Project AB have 2 dependency project (A&B) and Main project CD have 2 dependency (C&D). If there is any change in project A or B, it should trigger main project AB. If there is any change in project C or D, it should trigger main project CD. How to write this condition in gitlab-ci.yml file? Do we need multiple .gitlab-ci.yml file for each project ?

```
  master
  - Dependency Project A
  - Dependency Project B
  - Main Project AB
  - Dependency Project C
  - Dependency Project D
  - Main Project CD
  - .gitlab-ci.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would need a `.gitlab-ci.yml` in each project, but you have a couple of options in how to trigger the jobs.

Regardless of which method of triggering you choose (below), all your dependency projects should have a CI file specifying the conditions to trigger the main project's CI. The main project's CI file should specify the various jobs

#### Multi-project pipeline (paid feature)

Docs: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/multi_project_pipelines.html

The easiest option is to write your CI so that commits in the dependencies trigger a downstream pipeline in the appropriate main project's CI.

#### Trigger API

Docs: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/README.html#adding-a-new-trigger

Another option is to use the trigger API by adding a curl command in your dependency projects' CI job. In this case, a ref is required.

In the main project's CI, you can specify jobs that [only run with a trigger token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyexcept-basic).